# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Migration - ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am getting a strange error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in AdminController#edit_user
NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for 663:Fixnum: SELECT privileges.*, ...

In: app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:75:in `edit_user'
```

**Here is the line in question:**

```
#line #75 from admin_controller.rb
@privileges = Privilege.find_by_sql( "SELECT privileges.*, vendors.name AS vendor_name FROM privileges LEFT JOIN vendors ON vendors.id = rivileges.vendor_id WHERE user_id = ?  ORDER BY vendors.name", @user.id)
```

I can fix it by taking out the placeholder but I do not want to do this:

```
@privileges = Privilege.find_by_sql( "SELECT privileges.*, vendors.name AS vendor_name FROM privileges LEFT JOIN vendors ON vendors.id = privileges.vendor_id WHERE b2b_user_id = "+@user.id.to_s+"  ORDER BY vendors.name")
```

find_by_sql hasn't been deprecated in Rails 3 and I can pump that query into the database just fine.

What's strange to me is that there is no call to "empty?" in my  admin_controller. Is this an internal call to empty by Rails?

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: in the first query, you mention it as rivileges.vendor_id WHERE. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

This syntax has been deprecated in Rails 3.1.

You should call

```
@privileges = Privilege.find_by_sql ["SELECT privileges.*, vendors.name AS vendor_name FROM privileges LEFT JOIN vendors ON vendors.id = rivileges.vendor_id WHERE user_id = ?  ORDER BY vendors.name", @user.id]
```